# Select Specific Portion of Regex Search

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2 I want to select just the 4th occurrence of a double-quote in a line that contains at least 7 double-quotes.  I want to do this with a find all so each of the 4th occurrences of the double-quotes is selected. I have the following search criteria to find lines with at least 7 double-quotes:

```
".*".*".*".*".*".*".*
```

I want a cursor at each 4th quote like this (| meaning cursor):

```
"test",123,456,"more |"testing", "test1"
"test",123,456,"other |"testing", "test2"
```

"Find All" selects the full row and not just the 4th double-quote.  I know you can mostly the same things using a replace instead of cursors in each location.  For example:

```
Find What: (".*".*".*".*)"(.*".*".*)
Replace With: $1<anything you want>$2
```

But I really want the option to type with cursors at the point of each 4th quote as there is additional functionality I'd like to use.

Comment: Is the real string: `"test",123,456,"more"testing", "test1"` or `"test",123,456,"more","testing", "test1"` ?

Comment: replace the dots with `[^"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match the 4th quote:

```
^(?:[^"\n]*"){3}[^"\n]*\K"(?=(?:[^"\n]*"){3})
```

[image]

or the position before the 4th double quote:

```
^(?:[^"\n]*"){3}[^"\n]*\K(?="(?:[^"\n]*"){3})
```

[image]

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU1vY5/1)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of line
- `(?:[^"\n]*"){3}` - 3 occurrences of zero or more characters other than double quote and a newline followed with a double quote, followed with...
- `[^"\n]*` - zero or more characters other than double quote and a newline
- `\K` - an operator omitting all the text matched so far
- `"` - the 4th double quote on a line
- `(?=(?:[^"\n]*"){3})` - that is followed with 3  occurrences of zero or more characters other than double quote and a newline followed with a `"`.